# Why $.extend(window, window, someobject) triggers page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have object like this:

```
var example = {
    test1: 10,
    test2: 20,
    test3: 30
}
```

For some reason, I wanted to use `test#` variables without `example`, so I extended `window` object like this(using jQuery):

```
$.extend(window, window, example)
```

But, whenever this function has called, page was refreshed.

And one more question, if I try to extend `document` in the same way, some error occurs like this:(in Chrome)

> Error: NAMESPACE_ERR: DOM Exception 14

Why is that? And is there any way to use variables without object(namespace) name?

Comment: Why are you passing `window` twice?  Does it work if you do just `$.extend(window, example)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `$.extend` call does the equivalent of this:

```
window.location = window.location;
```

And that will refresh the page.

The [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) function essentially copies all the properties (using simple assignments) from the second through last arguments to the first argument and returns the (updated) first argument. In your second argument, `window`, there will be `location` property and when you assign something to `window.location`, you change the page and if the new and old `location` values are the same, you'll refresh the current page.

If you want to add all the properties in `example` to `window`, just do this:

```
$.extend(window, example);
```

As far as "And is there any way to use variables without object(namespace) name?" goes, just add your variables as properties of `window` and you'll be able to access them without a prefix:

```
window.where_is = "pancakes house?";
alert(where_is);
```

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/T7cNx/

Comment: That's great answer. I forgot to use `$.extend(window, example)`. Anyway, I got some new information. Thank you!